# Regex with a variable and not followed by anything in R

Tags: r, regex

Once again, I'm struggling with Regex!
I need to find, in R with the `grep` function, an expression:

- which includes a dynamic variable (a value that changes in a loop)
- and not followed by any character (a dot or a number).

Below an example:

```
for (j in 1:2){
     aaa = c(0,-0.5)
     JOP = c("one.HR0","twoHR0", "oneHR0.5", "twoHR0.5") 
     print(grep(paste0("HR", abs(aaa[j]),"?!."), JOP))}
```

In my example, I want to get `one.HR0`,`twoHR0` in the first loop and so on.

But my Regex is not working! 
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: What defines a "variable" and what exactly does "anything" mean when you say it can't be followed by anything. Does your definition rely on knowing all the other elements in the list? If so, a regex probably isn't going to help you since those test happen with one element at a time. What if there was just "o" in the list. Would you ignore "one.HR0" and "oneHR0.5" as well? Are you just trying to get rid of the values that end in ".5"?

Comment: @MrFlick I know the elements in my list. it does not contain just "o".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do, what you're after?

```r
for (j in 1:2){
  aaa = c(0,-0.5)
  JOP = c("one.HR0","twoHR0", "oneHR0.5", "twoHR0.5") 
  print(grep(paste0("HR", abs(aaa[j]),"$"), JOP, value=T)) #value=T returns actual values and not only the matching indexes in JOP
  }
```

Comment: Yes, it's working! Thanks a lot. What does the "$" means ? Sorry, I'm not familiar with Regex.

Comment: `$` means the end of the string. Similarly, `^` means the beginning of the string, if you want to find a string that starts with something.

Comment: I learned with this: https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html   . It also has a tutorial on the fallacies with R (that needs to have some modifications compared to many other languages) https://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html For example the need for double `\\`

Comment: @MrFlick There are characters before  the expression I'm looking for and your solution does not work in my case. I tried it on the loop used in the example and on my real data. Thanks anyway :-)